# Powershell how to know if a list's elements are numbered consecutively

Tags: powershell, sequence

I´m trying to know if all the PC are in the list and if one it´s not on the list the script will say me, the list can be modificate with more PC.

```
$equipos= "equipo1","equipo2","equipo3","equipo5"
[char]$nequipos = 1

for($i=0;$i -lt $equipos.count;$i++){
    [char]$num = $equipos[$i][6]
    if($num -ne $nequipos){
    write-host "equipo"$nequipos
    }
[char]$nequipos= $i++
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following finds the gaps in the numbering and lists all available names based on the missing numbers:

```
# Extract all numbers contained in the names.
[int[]] $numbers =  "equipo1", "equipo2", "equipo3", "equipo5" -replace '\D'
# Find the highest number.
$highestNumber = [Linq.Enumerable]::Max($numbers)

# Find all unused numbers.
$unusedNumbers = Compare-Object $numbers (1..$highestNumber) -PassThru

# Report results.
if ($unusedNumbers) {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "The following names are available: "
  $unusedNumbers.ForEach({ 'equipo' + $_ })
} else {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "No gaps in numbering found."
}
```

Output:

```
VERBOSE: The following names are available:
equipo4
```

Note:

- [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) `'\D'` removes all non-digit (`\D`) characters from the names and casts the resulting strings to `[int[]]` in order to get an array of *numbers*.
- `[Linq.Enumerable]::Max($numbers)` finds the maximum (highest number) among them. See the [.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Max).
- [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) is used to compare the extracted numbers to the (gap-less) *range* ([`..`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-)) of numbers from `1` to the highest one (`1..$highestNumber`). By default, the elements that are *different* between the input collections are reported and, thanks to `-PassThru`, those extracted numbers that are missing from the range are directly output.
- `$unusedNumbers.ForEach({ 'equipo' + $_ })` uses the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) to construct the list of names for the unused numbers in the range.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the names are unique, you can pick the highest number in the sequence and subtract the length of the list - that'll give you the number of gaps:

```
$equipos = "equipo1","equipo2","equipo3","equipo5" |Sort-Object {$_ -replace '^\D+' -as [int]} -Unique -Descending 

$highest = $equipos |Select -First 1
$number = $highest -replace '^\D+' -as [int]
if($number -gt $equipos.Length){
  "There are $($number - $equipos.Length) gap(s) in the list"
} 
else {
  "The list is contiguous"
}
```

Which, with the given sample values, will output:

```
There are 1 gap(s) in the list
```